# Detect double date in range and adjust date

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
library(hydroGOF)
library(ModelMetrics)
library(dplyr)
Date_from <- c("2013-01-01","2013-01-04","2013-01-06","2013-01-11")
Date_to <- c("2013-01-03","2013-01-06","2013-01-10","2013-01-14")
Parameter <- c("Par1","Par1","Par1","Par1")
conc<-c("1.5","2.5","1.5","1.8")
metals<-data.frame(Date_from,Date_to,Parameter,conc)
metals$Date_from<-as.Date(metals$Date_from)
metals$Date_to<-as.Date(metals$Date_to)
metals$conc<-as.numeric(as.character(metals$conc))
```

I need to detect the wrong starting date in a date range. In this example it would be the third range starting from 2013-01-06 which is the end date of the second date range. I need the code to detect this and adjust the starting date one day after the end of the previous date range. The result should look like this:

```
Date_from    Date_to Parameter conc
2013-01-01 2013-01-03      Par1  1.5
2013-01-04 2013-01-06      Par1  2.5
2013-01-07 2013-01-10      Par1  1.5
2013-01-11 2013-01-14      Par1  1.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
ind = which(difftime(metals$Date_to,lead(metals$Date_from))==0)+1 #search for time difference == 0, save the index

metals[ind,"Date_from"] = metals[ind,"Date_from"] + 1 # add a day to the start date
```

Answer (score 1):

we can use `dplyr::lag`

```
 library(dplyr)
 metals %>% mutate(Date_from_u=lag(Date_to,default=0), 
                   Date_from_corr=if_else(Date_from==Date_from_u,Date_from+1,Date_from))
```

Answer (score 1):

`lubridate` here. The key is to use `if_else` instead of `ifelse`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
metals %>% 
  mutate_if(is.Date,as.Date.character) %>% 
  mutate(Date_from=ymd(Date_from),Date_to=ymd(Date_to),
         Date_from=if_else(Date_from%in%Date_to,Date_from+1,Date_from))


# Date_from    Date_to    Parameter conc
#1 2013-01-01 2013-01-03      Par1  1.5
#2 2013-01-04 2013-01-06      Par1  2.5
#3 2013-01-07 2013-01-10      Par1  1.5
#4 2013-01-11 2013-01-14      Par1  1.8
```